# Como listar dados relacionados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

Em meu projeto tenho duas tabelas: Aluno e Ocorrencias. E elas estão relacionadas de forma que um aluno pode ter várias ocorrências. A minha necessidade é: Na view de Detalhes do aluno(Detalhes.cshtml), preciso mostrar todas as ocorrências relacionadas ao aluno. Ou seja, todas as ocorrências que tenham relação ao nome dele. Já tentei de várias formas só que não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Já estou meio perdido, já procurei pelos erros que recebo, mas nada que me ajude. Já tentei usar partials, mas como fazer a lista de ocorrências é um IEnumerable, dá conflito de Models ao carregar a view de detalhes.
Será que alguém poderia me dar um norte de como fazer isso ?

## Controller(Aluno)

```
    // GET: /Alunos/Detalhes/5
    public ActionResult Detalhes(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.Find(id);
        if (aluno == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(aluno);
    }
```

## View(Detalhes)

```
 @model CEF01.Models.Aluno

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detalhes";
 }

 <div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
     </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome) <br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Foto)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <img src="@Model.Foto" border="0" width="150px" height="160px"/>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomePai)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomePai)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeMae)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomeMae)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Endereco)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Endereco)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataDeNascimento)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataDeNascimento)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnoLetivo)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AnoLetivo)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ano)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ano)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Turma)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Turma)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Numero)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Numero)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Turno)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Turno)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telefone)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefoneContato)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TelefoneContato)<br />
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelefoneResponsavel)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TelefoneResponsavel)<br />
    </dd>

    </dl>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
       @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edita", new { id = Model.Id }) |
              @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para lista", "Index")
    </p>

                    <h3>Ocorrencias</h3>
                  @Html.Partial("PartialDetalhesOcorrencias", Model.Ocorrencias)
```

## Partial(Ocorrencias do Aluno)

```
@model IEnumerable<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>

 @{

 }

  <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Aluno.Nome)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tipo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Causa)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aluno.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Causa)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

   </table>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar pra gente como está o código do Controller?

Comment: Ta do jeito normal que vem do scaffolding. Fiz o scaffolding e gerei as views. Só pra tentar colocar esses dados da ocorrências to tentando usar partial view. E nela esta o IEnumerable, mas num ta dando certo.

Comment: Então coloque o código do Controller e das Views gerado, por favor.

Comment: Feito ! As alterações estao ai !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou a carga explícita das ocorrências. Modifique sua `Action` de detalhes para o seguinte:

```
[PermissionAttribute("Administrador,Coordenador")]
// GET: /Alunos/Detalhes/5
public ActionResult Detalhes(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.Include(a => a.Ocorrencias).SingleOrDefault(id);

    if (aluno == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(aluno);
}
```

O método `Include` indica ao Entity Framework que você fará a carga explícita das ocorrências do aluno na pesquisa.

Se eu não ne engano, `Include` não funciona com `Find`.

Comment: Dai eu posso carregar a partial com um foreach que mostra ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Isso mesmo.

Comment: Nossa cara, vou testar aqui então ! Porque estou a horas com isso e não consigo fazer funcionar ! Deixa eu ver aqui ! Só uma coisa, vou colocar a minha partial pra carregar, ai vê se ta certo ?

Comment: Sim, só atualize a pergunta caso dê errado que eu atualizo a resposta na sequência.

Comment: Funcionou aqui !